# Passing a list of contrasts read as characters to a linear mode in R

Tags: r, lm, contrast

Probably missing something basic here.

I have `XY` data to which I want to fit an `lm` in R:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = c("0h","0h","4h","4h","8h","8h","10h","10h"),
                 y = rnorm(8))
```

Fitting the `lm` is part of a function that receives as input the `df` and also the type of `contrast` that should be set. The `contrast` is read as a user input and hence is a `character`.

For example:

```
my.contrast <- "contr.helmert(4)"
```

I then want to pas this to contrast a `model.matrix` with which the `lm` will then be fitted.

I'm trying:

```
contrast.list <- list(x = my.contrast)
design.mat <- model.matrix(y ~ x, data = df, contrasts.arg = contrast.list)
```

But obviously getting the error:

```
Error in get(ctr, mode = "function", envir = parent.frame()) : 
  object 'contr.helmert(4)' of mode 'function' was not found
```

However, it's not clear to me what type I should convert `my.contrast` to for the `model.matrix` to work.

Obviously,

```
model.matrix(y ~ x, data = df, contrasts.arg = list(x = contr.helmert(4)))
```

Works fine

Comment: Are you sure you want the `(4)`. It looks to me like you don't need to set `n`. `my.contrast <- "contr.helmert"` works fine.

Comment: I was following the reverse Helmert contrast exmaple from: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/#HELMERT

Comment: In https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/#HELMERT they also have 4 levels in their `x`. You're right that the I'm getting the same matrix by using `"contr.helmert"` but it doesn't have the same `attributes` part as the one produced using `contr.helmert(4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try with `eval`

```
model.matrix(y ~ x, data = df, contrasts.arg = eval(parse(text=my.contrast)))
  (Intercept) x10h x4h x8h
1           1    0   0   0
2           1    0   0   0
3           1    0   1   0
4           1    0   1   0
5           1    0   0   1
6           1    0   0   1
7           1    1   0   0
8           1    1   0   0
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$`x`
[1] "contr.treatment"
```